# Delete Temp files generated by using CompileAssemblyFromSource in c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# application which generates temp files at `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp`. These temp files are being generated as a result of using `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource`. For each dynamic assembly following files (.tmp, .out, .err, .dll, .pdb, .cmdline, .cs) are generated. I tried to use

```
result.TempFiles.KeepFiles = false;
```

but this is not deleting these temp files automatically. How can I get rid of these temp files before the end of c# application execution ?

Answer (score 1):

`KeepFiles` seems to only be a [flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection.keepfiles(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Each temporary file
>   in the collection has an associated keep file flag that determines, on
>   a per-file basis, whether that file is to be kept or deleted. Files
>   are automatically kept or deleted on completion of the compilation
>   based on their associated keep files value. However, after compilation
>   is complete, files that were kept can be released by setting **KeepFiles
>   false and calling the Delete method.** This will result in all files
>   being deleted.

Will either need to call [`TempFileCollection.Delete`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/codedom/compiler/TempFiles.cs,68f41153b79d2d22) or using [`TempFileCollection.Dispose()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/codedom/compiler/TempFiles.cs,68f41153b79d2d22):

When you're done using the collection:

```
result.TempFiles.Delete();
```

Or

```
result.TempFiles.Dispose();
```

Which are equivalent.

Comment: I am marking the flag `result.TempFiles.KeepFiles = false;` after the statement `result = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource` and then using `result.TempFiles.Dispose();`  Should KeepFiles flag be raised before using CompileAssemblyFromSource ?

Comment: @Anky `KeepFiles` should be false before you invoke `Delete` so it knows not to keep any files.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want those temporary files to be generated at all then use `CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;` before using/calling `CompileAssemblyFromSource`

Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateinmemory(v=vs.110).aspx